# Optimizing an implementation of BFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I am learning the basics of Graph and got into solving the problem from
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach. The code is working fine but i am getting TLE for a single test case. I changed the cin/cout to printf/scanf hoping to getting it accepted but didn't work out. The code I have till now is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct Graph
{
    int size;
    std::list<int> *adj;
};

Graph* createGraph(int size)
{
    Graph *graph = new Graph();
    graph->size = size;
    graph->adj = new std::list<int>[size];
    return graph;
}
void addEdge(Graph *graph, int source, int dest)
{
    graph->adj[source].push_back(dest);
    graph->adj[dest].push_back(source);
}

void printGraph(Graph *graph)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->size; ++i)
    {
        for(std::list<int>::iterator it = graph->adj[i].begin(); it!= graph->adj[i].end(); ++it)
          {
            std::cout<<*it<<' ';
          }
          std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

void BFS(Graph *graph, int src)
{
    std::queue <int> nodes;
    std::vector<bool> v(graph->size,false);
    std::vector<int> distance(graph->size, INT_MAX);
    v[src] = true;
    distance[src] = 0;
    nodes.push(src);
    std::list<int>::iterator it;
    while(!nodes.empty())
    {
        int temp = nodes.front();
        v[temp] = true;
        nodes.pop();
        for(it = graph->adj[temp].begin(); it!= graph->adj[temp].end(); ++it)
          {
            if(!v[*it])
            {
                nodes.push(*it);
                int current = distance[temp] != INT_MAX? distance[temp] : 0;
                distance[*it] = std::min(current + 6, distance[*it]);
            }
          }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); ++i)
    {
        int dist = distance[i] != INT_MAX ?  distance[i] : -1;
        if(i!= src)
        {
            printf("%d ", dist);
        }
    }
        printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int T;
    scanf(" %d", &T);
    while(T--) {
        int n, m, s;
        // cin>>n>>m;m
        scanf(" %d %d", &n, &m);
        Graph *graph = createGraph(n);
        while(m--)
        {
            int x, y;
            // cin>>x>>y;
            scanf(" %d %d", &x, &y);
            addEdge(graph, x-1, y-1);
        }
        // cin>>s;
        scanf(" %d", &s);
        BFS(graph, s-1);
        // printGraph(graph);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that the time complexity of this algorithm of `O(m log n)` . And the time complexity required to insert a edge is  `O(1)` . So AFAIK, this is the best we can do(maybe?). I am not sure that if this is the best way to store the graph. Any better and faster approach  to store a graph and suggestion to improve this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a matter of optimization. You should set visited of every node you put in queue `true` right after you put them in `queue` or else you will revisit some nodes a lot of time. You are putting a `node` in queue but not setting its visited to `true` and delaying this until you take that node out of queue then you set the its visited to `true`. So what happens? Consider this Graph `V={a,b,c,d}` , `E={a->b, a->c, a->d, b->d, c->d}`. First `a` pushes `b,c,d` in queue but doesn't set their visited. Then `b` pushes `d` to the queue, and after that `c` also pushes `d` to the queue. So your queue looks like this `q={d,d,d}`. So you are going to visit `d` three times. And this was very small case, you can see for large cases how could this result in a big issue.

Something like this:

```
queue <int> q;
q.push(source);
visited[source] = true;
while ( q.size() ){
    int current_node = q.front();
    q.pop();
    for ( int i=0; i<adjacencyList[current_node].size(); ++i ){
        int next_node = adjacencyList[current_node][i];
        if ( visited[next_node] )
            continue;
        dist[next_node] = dist[current_node] + 1;
        visited[next_node] = 1;
        q.push(next_node);
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. I though long and hard about it and didn't do it. I'll have to revisit the topic i guess. Anyway Thanks :)

Comment: BTW, I would probably use a graph structure like this for  a programming contest: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13703306/